# Etimologia de "Dia das Bruxas"

Tags: etimologia

O nome "*Dia das Bruxas*" tem nenhuma relação com a palavra em inglês "*Halloween*" quando se comparam os seus significados traduzidos (em ambas as líguas), embora "*Dia das Bruxas*" seja a versão da denominação "*Halloween*" em português.

De onde surgiu este nome em português?

**Obs**.: a pergunta não é sobre a origem da celebração celta e sua mistura ou assimilação cristã até os dias de hoje, nem sobre a etimologia de Halloween (*All hallow's eve*) mas apenas sobre a origem da versão do nome em português.

**Atualização 1:** encontrei uso de "*Día de Brujas*" em espanhol, mas parece ser menos comum que *"Día de Muertos*" e "*Día de Todos los Santos*".

**Atualização 2:** segundo este [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nilTpWBR4d8) do Nerdologia (canal que produz conteúdo científico com linguagem e cultura pop) o termo "Dia das Bruxas" em português teria surgido da tradução livre de desenhos animados dos EUA no Brasil.

Comment: É o que eu descrevi na própria pergunta em "OBS". Apenas não traduzi para "Dia de todos os santos" @ANeves

Comment: A primeira ocorrência que encontrei foi entre [1871 a 1891](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=890820&pesq=Dia%20das%20Bruxas&pasta=ano%20187). A etimologia, acho difícil defini-la. Talvez seja porque, no EUA, as fantasias de bruxas fossem mais comuns.  Esperarei um por uma resposta também.

Comment: Hihi, pois, não ligues Luciano que é segunda-feira... :)

Comment: Em Portugal também é chamado Dia das Bruxas ou é apenas uma tradução de PT-BR? Achei isso -> "Há, portanto, um Halloween. “Dia das Bruxas” é invenção com péssima tradução para brasileiras que nada tem a ver com o original."

Aqui tem um texto sem referência forte, mas pode ajudar -> http://sensoincomum.org/2016/10/31/nao-existe-dia-bruxas-halloween/

Comment: @Peixoto a maioria das vezes eu ouço as pessoas a dizerem Halloween, mas para publico mais velho as pessoas já tendem a dizer Dia das Bruxas, por eles não entenderem ou não saberem dizer.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, esse ["dia das bruxas e dos duendes" de 1879](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=890820&pesq=Dia%20das%20Bruxas&pasta=ano%20187) que tu encontraste, não se refere ao Halloween; é um 28 de dezembro em Espanha. Nalguns sítios em Espanha, comemoram nessa data o dia dos santos inocentes; mas pelo que eu vi, as comemorações não têm nada que ver com bruxas ou duendes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ***Halloween*** foi também conhecido por ***witches’ night***, e aparentemente foi este nome que na década de 1920 foi traduzido para português como ***noite das bruxas*** e adaptado para ***dia das bruxas***. Aliás, até 1936, *noite das bruxas* é bastante mais frequente que *dia das bruxas*; mas muito mais frequente ainda era *festa das bruxas*, possivelmente por estes termos ocorrerem quase exclusivamente em notícias sobre festas promovidas por casinos cariocas.
Alguns exemplos anteriores de *dias das bruxas* não têm que ver com o Halloween.

### *Witches’ Night* e o *Halloween*

Diz a [*Encyclopedia of Superstitions, Folklore, and the Occult Sciences*  (1903, p. 1487)](https://archive.org/details/encyclopaediasu00unkngoog/page/n235) que:

> Hallowe’en was called the “Witches’ Night,” “the Devil’s Sunday,” when his Satanic majesty was supposed to have full charge of all mundane things.
>
> [Minha tradução:] O *Halloween* era chamado a “Noite das Bruxas”,  “o Domingo do Diabo”, quando sua Satânica majestade era suposta ter o comando de todas as coisas mundanas.

Estes nomes parecem ter origem numa lenda acerca de uma reunião das bruxas sob orientação do Diabo nessa noite. Na página 1483, a enciclopédia narra outra lenda diferente de uma reunião das bruxas na noite de Haloween.

Os termos ***witches’ night*** ou ***withch-night*** aparecem com frequência no lugar de *Halloween* na imprensa norte-americana do princípio do século XX. Por exemplo:

> These boys have a wrong conception of **Hallowe’en**, believing the only way to celebrate the **witches’ night** is by the wanton destruction of property.
> [“Unruly boys land in jail for their fun,” Tonopah Daily Bonanza, Las Vegas, 31-10-1911](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86076142/1911-10-31/ed-1/seq-1/#date1=1890&index=8&date2=1920&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=night+witches&proxdistance=5&state=&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=witches+night&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1),

Mais alguns exemplos (links ao texto integral, com texto destacada a cor-de-rosa): [The Sun, (Nova Iorque, 1905)](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030272/1905-10-30/ed-1/seq-12/#date1=1789&index=5&date2=1920&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Night+Witch&proxdistance=5&state=New+York&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=witches+night&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), [The Sun (Nova Iorque, 1907)](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030272/1907-10-19/ed-1/seq-7/#date1=1789&index=9&date2=1920&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Night+Witch&proxdistance=5&state=New+York&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=witches+night&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1),  [Evening World, (Washington DC, 1911)](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030193/1911-10-27/ed-1/seq-19/#date1=1789&index=3&date2=1920&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=night+witch&proxdistance=5&state=New+York&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=witches+night&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), [Valdez Daily Prospector (Alaska, 1916)](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn98060264/1916-10-31/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1912&index=8&rows=20&words=Night+Witches&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1917&proxtext=witches+night&y=15&x=14&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), [East Oregonian, (Pendleton, 1918)](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88086023/1918-10-26/ed-1/seq-11/#date1=1900&index=0&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=night+witches&proxdistance=5&date2=1928&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=witches+night&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2), [New York Tribune (1921)](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030214/1921-10-30/ed-1/seq-62/#date1=1900&index=19&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Night+Witches&proxdistance=5&date2=1928&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=witches+night&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), [The Seatle Star (1922)](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn87093407/1922-10-31/ed-1/seq-1/#date1=1900&sort=relevance&date2=1928&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=8&words=NIGHT+WITCHES&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=witches+night&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=4), [*Evening Star* (Washington DC, 1928)](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1928-10-28/ed-1/seq-63/#date1=1921&sort=relevance&date2=1928&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=7&words=witch-night&proxdistance=5&state=&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=witches+night&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2).

### “Noite das bruxas” no Rio de Janeiro a partir de 1928

Não sei se ainda se o nome *witches’ night* ainda continua em uso, mas em 1928 ainda aparecia na imprensa norte-americana. E foi precisamente a partir de 1928 que na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://memoria.bn.br/hdb/periodico.aspx), que tem o texto integral de centenas de periódicos brasileiros dos últimos dois séculos, surgem pela primeira vez, em referência ao Halloween, os termos ***noite das bruxas***, ***dia das bruxas*** e sobretudo ***festa das bruxas***.

O grande responsável foi o Beira-Mar Casino do Rio de Janeiro, que de 1928 a 1936 celebrou a ocasião, com uma festa “dedicada à colónia norte-americana”. Em 1931 teve concorrência da boite Maxim, e em 1934 do Casino da Urca. Todos estes eventos foram amplamente noticiados na imprensa carioca. Depois de 1936, desaparecem das páginas dos jornais as referências a *festa*, *noite* ou *dia das bruxas*, para só reaparecerem em meados dos anos 50, agora já em vários pontos do Brasil.

O nome comummente usado nas notícias é *festa das bruxas* — aparece em 130 artigos de 1928 a 1936; *noite das bruxas* aparece em 20 artigos, e *dia das bruxas* apenas em 3 (o mesmo artigo reproduzido em três jornais; as outros números também incluem repetições). Deixo aqui alguns excertos de notícias de 1928:

> **“A festa das bruxas” (All hallow’s Eve), no Beira Mar Casino.**
>
> Não é uma festa commum, das muitas que semanalmente o Beira Mar Casino celebra, a que vai realizar-se na noite do dia 31 do corrente e que é dedicada á colonia norte-americana, que obedecendo sempre ás suas tradições e seus costumes não esquece o seu dia: “All hallow’s Eve” ou seja o **“Dia das bruxas”**.
> [*Jornal do Brasil*, Rio de Janeiro, 20-10-1928](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_04&pesq=%22festa%20das%20bruxas%22&pasta=ano%20192)
>
> O acontecimento do mez que vai findar é o de amanhã, á noite, no Beira Mar Casino, onde se realiza a tradicional festa norte-americana da **“Noite de bruxas”**.
> A **“Festa das bruxas”** conta com mil motivos de exito […]
> [“Diversões”, *O Paiz*, Rio de Janeiro, 30-10-1928](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/docmulti.aspx?bib=%5Bcache%5Ddrummond_4390702635157.DocLstX&pasta=ano%20192&pesq=%22noite%20bruxas%22)
>
> *A **Festa das Bruxas** — a americanissima, exotica* All Hallow’s Eve — *foi o* clou *social, elegante e chic da semana. Era uma coisa excentrica, e Melindrosa não poderia faltar, como não faltou. Com seu rostinho pallido,* maquillé *em arco-iris, era ella a mais linda e encantadora bruxinha que se exhibia naquele salão indiano, ornamentado e illuminado a* propos.
> [“Sombras Chinezas”, *Fon-Fon*, Rio de Janeiro, 10-11-1928](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=259063&pesq=%22festa%20das%20bruxas%22&pasta=ano%20192)

### Outros usos de *dia das bruxas* antes de 1928

Encontram-se algumas ocorrências de *dia das bruxas* anteriores a 1928, mas não se referem ao *Halloween*.

Nuns casos referem-se a uma sexta-feira; aparentemente uma qualquer. Por razão que desconheço, gerou-se a ideia de que sexta-feira é o dia das bruxas. Exemplos no [Diário do Rio de Janeiro (1875)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=094170_02&pesq=%22dia%20das%20bruxas%22&pasta=ano%20187), [Gazeta Luzitana, (Rio de Janeiro, 1885)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=348996&pesq=%22dia%20das%20bruxas%22&pasta=ano%20188), [Correio Paraense (1893)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=302619&pesq=%22noite%20das%20bruxas%22&pasta=ano%20183) (neste caso é uma “noute das bruxas”) e [Diario de S. Luiz (1922)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=093874&pesq=%22dia%20das%20bruxas%22&pasta=ano%20192)

Noutros casos, é o sábado que é o dias das bruxas. É o caso no [Commercio de São Paulo (1894)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=227900&pesq=%22dia%20das%20bruxas%22&pasta=ano%20189), e “dias das bruxas e dos duendes” no [Jornal da Noite (Rio de Janeiro, 1878-79)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=890820&pesq=%22dia%20das%20bruxas%22&pasta=ano%20187), apontado nos comentários acima pelo Valdeir. Isto parece vir da ideia do [sábado ou sabbat das bruxas (Wikipedia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbat), já mencionada em 1828 pelo [Almeida Garrett (*Adozinda*, p. 117)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=-ApgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=%22bruchas%20celebrando%22&source=bl&ots=E8hMp4I1bJ&sig=ACfU3U2tAya5MIu6eIdbOyppcyD0kMr7vw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdsufP6NPlAhV_AWMBHRf2DTYQ6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22bruchas%20celebrando%22&f=false).

Esta ideia de haver um dia das bruxas (pelos vistos, todas as semanas!), mesmo não tendo nada que ver com o *Halloween*, talvez facilitasse a adoção dos termos *dia* ou *noite das bruxas* para designar as celebrações, dado as bruxas serem um tema proeminente no *Halloween*.

### Curiosidade: o “trick or treat” e o “pão por deus”

Nos Estados Unidos não há Halloween sem “trick or treat”. Em Portugal há o “pão por deus”, que tem algumas semelhanças e claramente a mesma origem. O [trick or treat (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trick-or-treating) tem origem no *guising* da Escócia e Irlanda, em que “no Halloween, pessoas iam mascaradas de porta em porta, recitando versos em troca de comida, e por vezes agoirando má-sorte quando não eram bem recebidas” (minha tradução da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trick-or-treating)).

Em Portugal e na Galiza há ou houve basicamente a mesma tradição, conhecida por [pão por deus (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A3o-por-Deus) nalgumas regiões. Há imensos relatos de crianças ou jovens irem no dia de Todos os Santos de porta em porta recitando versos pedindo “pão por deus” ou “bolinhos”, e retaliando com versos escarninhos ou agoirentos em caso de recusa. Outra coisa em comum é a comida nalguns lugares ser pedida para os mortos. Mais espantoso ainda, para mim, é uma tradição registada em Coimbra e Anadia: as crianças iam “ao cair da noite, com uma abóbora oca e com buracos recortados a fazer de olhos, nariz e boca, como se fosse uma caveira, e com um coto de vela aceso por dentro, para lhe dar um ar mais macabro” ([Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A3o-por-Deus))! Esta abóbora é um exemplo de representação de um *coco* ou [*coca* (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca_(folclore)) (pronunciados *côco, côca*), um ser mítico para assustar crianças, e segundo vários autores é uma tradição muito antiga em Portugal.

Estas tradições portuguesas são antigas e estão muito bem documentadas. Há registo delas já em [1851 nos Açores](https://books.google.pt/books?id=0YoDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA177&dq=%22p%C3%A3o%20por%20deus%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizy_KRtNDsAhUl2-AKHbgxCMQ4FBDoATAFegQICRAC#v=onepage&q=%22p%C3%A3o%20por%20deus%22&f=false) e em [1885 em Alpedriz](https://books.google.pt/books?id=xXnRDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA161&dq=%22p%C3%A3o%20por%20deus%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYo6mUutDsAhXVBGMBHV37CSUQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22p%C3%A3o%20por%20deus%22&f=false) (uns 100 km a norte de Lisboa). E há um [levantamento de meados do século XX destas tradições por todo o Portugal](https://books.google.pt/books?id=b57yDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&dq=%22p%C3%A3o%20por%20deus%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYo6mUutDsAhXVBGMBHV37CSUQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22p%C3%A3o%20por%20deus%22&f=false). Este inclui a zona em que eu cresci, arredores de Torres Vedras, e pelo menos neste caso o autor foi fidelíssimo: na minha aldeia a criançada limitava-se a ir de porta em porta pedindo “pão por deus”. Não me passava pela cabeça que havia em Portugal esta coisa dos versos e abóboras iluminadas! Há também registo destas tradições no estado de Santa Catarina, no Brasil ([Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca_(folclore)) e [Tradições de Florianópolis](https://www.nsctotal.com.br/noticias/bruxas-sao-personagens-do-folclore-de-florianopolis)).

Voltando à pergunta propriamente dita, o que eu não encontrei nestes relatos da tradição em Portugal, Galiza, e Santa Catarina, foi qualquer referência a bruxas. Também isto sugere que o nome *dia das bruxas* não vem da tradição luso-brasileira. Aliás, nenhum dos imensos anúncios e artigos sobre as “festas, “dias” e “noites das bruxas” na imprensa brasileira dos anos vinte e trinta faz qualquer alusão a tradições brasileiras ou portuguesas. O nome *dia das bruxas* inspirou-se portanto noutra tradição qualquer, provavelmente, tal como a celebração propriamente dita, no *witches’ night* do folclore norte-americano.

Comment: @Jorge, obrigado pelas correções. Vê lá tu que a Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira me avacalhou os links. Antes, procurares "festa das bruxas" com ou sem aspas dava no mesmo: aquilo achava-te as três palavras juntas. Agora não: sem aspas, aquilo indica-te qualquer página em que apareçam todas as palavras, mesmo que seja *festa* numa ponta e *bruxa* na outra. Conclusão, eu nunca punha aspas, e os meus links agora não vão diretamente à página certa. Já corrigi os 3 primeiros; tenho que corrigir os outros mais tarde. E é a mesma treta noutras respostas em que tenho links à Hemeroteca!

Comment: De nada, sempre às ordens. Isso é que vai ser uma trabalheira :)

Comment: @JorgeB., encontrei um método expedito. Basta editar o link no editor do SE, pondo %22 antes e depois da expressão a procurar.

Comment: @JorgeB., vê a última secção que eu acrescentei. Tu sabias destas tradições em Portugal, abóboras iluminadas (as cocas), e versos no pão por deus? Não sei se o nome é "pão por deus" aí na tua zona.

Comment: O nome tradicional nas Astúrias é «nueche d’ánimes» ou «nueche les animes» com algumas dessas tradições também (de origem celta), e antes da chegada e popularização da abóbora à península, usava-se nabos ocos.  *An mirandés*, pelo meu entender pede-se *pan das/d'almas*, mas teria de confirmá-lo

Comment: @user0721090601, na Escócia ainda se usavam nabos no século XIX. O artigo da Wikipédia diz que para a coca (não necessariamente para usar no pão por deus) usavam-se também cabaças e panelas. "Nueche d'ánimes" está de acordo com um aspeto da tradição de Santa Catarina, Brasil, em que se dizia que nessa noite as almas (dos mortos) faziam uma procissão, e em vários pontos de Portugal deixava-se comida para as almas virem comer. Em vários pontos de Portugal também se faz para a ocasião o "pão das almas", e há o "soul cake" britânico. Claramente tudo vindo de uma tradição comum pré-cristã.